# Identify a piece of image extracted from video while its playing

Tags: angular

I have extracted a piece of image from a video by converting into canvas. I have x,y coordinates and height and width of the image. I need to identify and highlight the same piece of image while its playing in angular 2+ typescript.

[image: Screen shot shown below for details]

Comment: you can append the canvas into html element

Comment: Do you have some code to show first?

Comment: Not sure how, but you can try to save the frame number and on same show div with x y set in css (you wrap your video with div with `position: relative` and then the div htat have x,y can have `position: absolute`) but this will show highlight only on one frame, If you will need to show on frame that looks the same but the character move then you will probably need some Image recognition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenCV.js to do a template search on the canvas element rendering the video. This should work if the template was extracted from the video  you are playing. Theol problem however could be the processing power and real time detection

You can write the component in angular and use the library as a dependency